# How to hide a region in a node (most preferably without a module)?

Tags: theming, 10

I want to hide the sidebar region only in my homepage.

CSS `display:none` for the sidebar region is not enough because main content won't expand to cover the actual region so I think about using a Drupal PHP hook or some ugly PHP command, if there is either of these for that purpose.

How to hide a region in a node (most preferably without a module)?

Comment: You'll want to create a page-level template, and then omit the region you don't want in the template. e.g. `page--front.html.twig`. Regions can be tricky to hide in certain cases, but a page template allows you to build the structure you want/need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default Drupal system of template hook that provide the possibility of overide any layout template according the current content type inside the template name.

For example if you want to overide the `page.html.twig` template for the front page you just have to create a new template file inside you front theme folder : `page--front.html.twig`

It's inside this template that you include the theme region so you can add only the regions you want inside it.

The default `page.html.twig` :

```
{{ page.header }}
{{ page.sidebar }}
{{ page.content }}
{{ page.footer }}
```

Your `page--front.html.twig` :

```
{{ page.header }}
{{ page.content }}
{{ page.footer }}
```

Be sure to clear your cache after with `drush cr` command.